# Linux find files

Tags: linux, command-line

What could be a command to find all files owned by "abc" user, I guess that can be extended to finding all files with group 'def'.

e.g.

if I got result (ls -l) such as one shown below

```
-rwxrw-r--   1 apache web      1981 2009-01-22 08:10 unsubscribe.php
```

then I would like to find all files owned by apache or group web

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` command has options for both. See the `find(1)` man page for more details.

Comment: thnx. so can I print the result in say ls -l format?

Comment: Absolutely. See the `-printf` or `-ls` predicates.

Answer (score 3):

`find /home/ -user <username> -group <groupname>`

and lots of other search criteria.

Comment: worked like charm. thnx

Answer (score 2):

Use the find program

```
find path -group group_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) there.  It has a whole language on the command line to let you specify what to list based on, including uid, username, gid, and group by name.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your questions:

```
find /path -type f  \( -user apache -o group web \) -exec ls -l {}; \
```

The find manpage is very much less than enlightening. IMO.